# jquery based drop down error

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/ub4rP/3/

When you click `origin` the drop-down thing works great, but when clicking outside, that is, the html body, nothing happens. I want the drop down to also close when clicking outside the `.scroller` div. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

What you have does actually work. See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ub4rP/4/), and click anywhere in the black area.

The problem is that `div` elements (as block elements) expand to take up all available width, which means the `.dd_content` element is as wide as the page, and if you click anywhere on that, it captures the click event and stops the propagation to the `body`.

Here's [another working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ub4rP/5/), this time with a fixed width set on `.dd_content` (click anywhere that's more than 100px to the right of `.dd_content`).

Comment: nice solution, I just fixed some bugs and added a css.
http://jsfiddle.net/ub4rP/8/